# seaborn heatmap - x axis - repeated values

Tags: visualization, graphs, seaborn, heatmap

I'm in trouble creating a heatmap using a CSV file.

csv data is in a format like below
[image]

here is a code

```
years = np.array(datadf.PublicationYear)

sns.set(font_scale=2)
wordlist = ['greenhouse_gas', 'pollution', 'resilience', 'urban','city', 'environmental_impacts', 'climate_change', 
            'adaptation','mitigation','carbon', 'ghg_emissions','sustainable','sustainability','lca']

word_tuples = [('urban','city','urban'), ('greenhouse_gas','ghg_emissions','greenhouse_gas'),('sustainable','sustainability','sustainability')]

use_wordlist = True
word_number = 30
freqdata = []
agg_keys = []

for i in np.arange(len(abstrct)):
    ngram_model = Word2Vec(ngram[[abstrct[i]]], size=100, min_count=1)
    ngram_model_counter = Counter()
    for key in ngram_model.wv.vocab.keys():

        if key not in stoplist:
            if use_wordlist:
                if key in wordlist:                   
                    if len(key.split("_")) > N:
                        ngram_model_counter[key] += ngram_model.wv.vocab[key].count
            else:
                if len(key.split("_")) > N:
                        ngram_model_counter[key] += ngram_model.wv.vocab[key].count
                
                
    freqdf = pd.DataFrame(ngram_model_counter.most_common(word_number))
    if len(freqdf.index) == 0:
        freqdf[0] = wordlist
        freqdf[1] = 0

    
    for w in word_tuples:
        if w[0] in wordlist and w[1] in wordlist:
            f = 0
            drops_w = []
            
            for j in np.arange(len(freqdf.index)):
                if freqdf.iloc[j][0] == w[0] or freqdf.iloc[j][0] == w[1]:
                    
                    f += freqdf.iloc[j][1]
                    drops_w.append(j)
                
            freqdf = freqdf.drop(drops_w, axis = 0)        
            append_data = pd.DataFrame({0:[w[2]],1:[f]})
            freqdf = freqdf.append(append_data,ignore_index=True)
            freqdf = freqdf.reset_index(drop=True)
            
                    
    #Normalizing the frequency by the total number of non-stopword tokens 
    freqdf['prob'] = freqdf[1]/(len(abstrct[i]))

    agg_keys += np.array(freqdf[0]).tolist()
    freqdata.append(freqdf)  
    
    
unqkeys = np.unique(np.array(agg_keys))

matrix = np.zeros([unqkeys.size,len(freqdata)])

for i in np.arange(years.size):
    
    for j in np.arange(unqkeys.size):
        
        for k in np.arange(len(freqdata[i].index)):
        
            if freqdata[i].iloc[k][0] == unqkeys[j]:
                matrix[j,i] = freqdata[i].iloc[k]['prob']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (40, 26))

ax = sns.heatmap(matrix, annot = False,linewidths = .9,cmap = 'Blues' ,cbar_kws={'label': 'Scaled Frequency'})
ax.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(35)


ax.grid(False)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(unqkeys))+0.5) #Adding 0.5 offset
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(years))+0.5)
ax.set_yticklabels(unqkeys,rotation= 0, fontsize = 34.0)
ax.set_xticklabels(years,rotation='vertical', fontsize = 35.0)
ax.set_xlabel('Publication Year', fontsize = 40.0, labelpad = 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Keywords',fontsize = 40.0, labelpad = 5)

plt.show()
image_path =  os.path.join(base_dir, 'plots/') + data_dir + '-heatmap.jpg'
fig.savefig(image_path)
```

It generates a graph below. How could it make x axis like [2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]
[image]

Comment: I think you might need to explain more about what you need to plot that will help others to understand and give you better solutions.

Comment: I would like to do grouping by year